# Drop-down selected value is not change when click on submit button

Tags: php, jquery

my issue is when i click on submit button any error in page to like(require field validation ) that time selected drop-down value is default value. but our requirement is not change drop-down value.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: elaborate more and show your code what is happening?

Comment: It's really confusing what are you trying to do

Comment: Better english would be a good starting point for asking a good question and getting some responses.

Comment: @Husman aswell as providing code and previous attempts at solving the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

NOTE : select value `$_REQUEST['test']` is compared with each value in option

```
<select name="test">
<option value="">Default</option>
<option value="value1" <?php if($_REQUEST['test'] == 'value1'){?> selected="selected" <?php }?>> value1</option>
<option value="value2" <?php if($_REQUEST['test'] == 'value2'){?> selected="selected" <?php }?>> value2</option>
<option value="value3" <?php if($_REQUEST['test'] == 'value3'){?> selected="selected" <?php }?>> value3</option>
<option value="value4" <?php if($_REQUEST['test'] == 'value4'){?> selected="selected" <?php }?>> value4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: +1 for coming up with an answer from that question ... :)